# Determining what media Backup Exec selects

Tags: backupexec

I have set up three backup jobs with `Backup Exec 2010`. It's a standard GFS, using a 24 slot Hp tape library. Right now we are just using 17 tapes. Slot 1-6 are daily, 7-10 are weekly and 11 and up are monthly.

In BE I've created three media sets:

- Daily: OPP 1 week, AP 1 week
- Weekly: OPP 5 weeks, AP 1 week
- Monthly: OPP Infinite, AP 1 week

This is the first backup to be made of the system. All tapes are currently associated with `scratch media`. Is it possible to determine exactly what tape BE will pick for the first backup? I.e I want the first full backup to be taken from slot 11 and monday from slot 1, tuesday from slot 2 etc.

Or do I just wait and see what BE choses and then write down afterwards what tapes were picked for each run?

Answer (score 2):

No it isn't possible. If you want to target your jobs at particular slots then partition the slots and target the jobs to the slots applicable to those jobs.

In my experience BackupExec usually pulls the tapes in order from lowest slot to highest slot. Since all of the tapes are Scratch media it's going to pull the first tape for the first job you run, whatever that job is. For the next job it's going to pull the next available tape from whatever slot has available Scratch media in it, and so on and so on. If you want your jobs to target specific physical slots then you need to partition the slots and set the Device for the applicable jobs to the appropriate slots.

Comment: So really, the best way to add info to the description of each media, i.e. Monday. Tuesday etc, is really to wait until BE has done a backup and placed the media in the corresponding library?